# Integral of $u\,dx+v\,dy$ for a complex polynomial $f(z)=u+iv$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

Let $C$ be a circle of fixed radius. What is the integral   $\int\limits_C u\,dx+v\,dy$ for a complex  polynomial  $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ where $z=x+iy$?

I think it should be $0$, but am not getting the exact proof. I think the integral equals $\operatorname{Re} \left(\int\limits_C \overline{f(z)} \, dz \right)$, which equals $\operatorname{Re}\left(\int\limits_C \frac{|f(z)|}{f(z)}\,dz\right)$. But, do the residues cancel out in the end? Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Apply green theorem

Comment: @Conrad If we apply Green's theorem, we get the integral equal to $\int\int_{int(C)}\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)dx dy$ which becomes, after application of Cauchy-Riemann, $\int\int_{int(C)}\left(-2\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)dx dy$. Now, how to proceed?

Comment: By linearity enough to show result for $f=z^n$ so then $u_y(x,y)=-u_y(x,-y)$ since $y$ appears only at odd powers; conclude

Comment: note that one needs real coefficients (so linearity is over the reals as we need for the above argument) btw -otherwise, for example, taking $f(z)=iz=-y+ix, u=-y, u_y=-1$ gives a non-zero integral